# Wordpress custorm URL variables causes strange redirect

Tags: wordpress, urlvariables, custom-url

I'm trying to have custom variables in my URL for Wordpress site.  I have read up as much as I could find on the subject and so far have the following in my functions page:

```
function add_query_vars($aVars) {
$aVars[] = "mrdrct";
return $aVars;
}

// hook add_query_vars function into query_vars
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars');
```

And the following on my header page:

```
if(isset($wp_query->query_vars['mrdrct'])) {
$mVar = $wp_query->query_vars['mrdrct'];
echo "variable is $mVar <br />";
}
```

Just to test out if things are being passed correctly and they are.  However, when I use a link with the url variable in it - say www.mydomain.com/?mrdrct=myVarable - I am not directed to my homepage of my Wordpress site which is set to a static page with a template on it - I am instead directed to a page with my latest posts on it.  I cannot figure out why this is happening - any ideas?  Hopefully I've explained this well enough.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When WP sees a query string (`?` after the URL) it will attempt to display matching posts using it's rewrite rules. If no posts match it will show a 404 error - I would guess you do not have a 404.php file, so WP is showing the default which is index.php (see the [Wordpress Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png) for more details on that).

I'm not 100% sure what you want to achieve, but I'd suggest that you need to look at changing the query when `$wp_query->query_vars['mrdrct']` is set. See the [WP Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) for `query_posts()` for a good place to start, if you are not already familier with it.

Comment: Thank you I will check these out, we do have a custom 404 page setup though, so I'm not sure why it's not hitting that instead.  What I'm basically trying to achieve is a link back to our full site from our mobile site - i was just setting a variable in link indicating the user wishes to view the full site rather than the mobile site.  Seemed simple enough in my head.

Comment: Nothing is ever as simple as it should be! There are lots of proper scripts out there for detecting borwsers and adding switching links, may be worth having a search on Google.